# recharts - event to know when rendering finished

Tags: reactjs, recharts

can't find anything in documentation about events emitted by the Recharts library - for example, when rendering finished. i want to attach `ref` to a component within a chart and once it's there calculate its height so i know it's not overflowing its parent:

```
const pieRef = useRef<Pie>(null);
...
<Pie
  // @ts-expect-error Type 'RefObject<Pie}>' is not assignable to type '(instance: Pie} | null) => void'.
  ref={pieRef}
  ...
>
```

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"recharts": "^2.4.3",
```

Answer (score 1):

`recharts` doesn't emit any events. On the next release an `onResize` callback will be available from `ResponsiveContainer` where you will be able to get the height and width of the chart container every time the window is resized (via `react-resize-detector`'s callback).

See [this issue](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/3326) and the linked PR in that issue.

Fixing refs will probably be a breaking change for 3.x.

Comment: i feel like i always try to approach problems from the unexplored path instead of comply with the current state :) thanks for keeping me up to date

Comment: sure thing! Looking for contributors if you'd like to help :)